# Minimal radius of a ball admitting a trivialization of a vector bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $p : V \to X$ a complex vector bundle of rank $n$. For $r > 0$ let $B(r,x)$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$. Does there exist an $r$ such that, for any $r'$, $0< r' \leq r$ and any $x \in X$, we have $p^{-1}(B(x, r')) \cong B(x, r') \times \mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue's_number_lemma

Comment: Looks good! Thanks!